# Search for filename with weighting

Tags: php

I do have thousands of files.
I want a user to be able to type in some word, and as a result he should get a list of file ordered by weighting based on the given words.
The position itself inside the string is irrelevant. The important thing is the distance between the given words. The further the words are seperated, the less important is the result. Partial matches are unimportant and should be shown at the bottom of the list.

Example:

searchstring: "foo bar"

expected result (the bold chars are just for visibility)

- **foo** **bar**.txt
- **foo** **bar** other long string.txt
- **foo**2 **bar** other long string.txt
- test **foo** **bar** other long string.txt
- test test **foo** qweqwe **bar** other long string.txt
- **foo** qweqwe.txt
- **bar** qweqwe.txt

I know levenshtein() but the longer the filename gets, it becomes less precise. Same with functions like similar_text()

for example: i am searching for 'DIN 107'

with 'similar_text()' i get:

- 'DIN 107 [1974-04].pdf' - 50%
- 'DIN 4107 [1978-01].pdf' - 48.3%
- 'DIN V 18035-6.pdf' - also 50%

but i want the user to see list as sorted above

What ist a good way to achieve this?

Comment: You have to make your search criteria explicit first. Do you want the position of the search words in the file name to make a difference? It seems that way, but I doubt that's a good idea. What about partial matches? We cannot make up this stuff for you.

Comment: yes, you are right.. i edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
<?php

$a = [
   'bar qweqwe.txt',
   'foo bar other long string.txt',
   'foo bar.txt',
   'foo qweqwe.txt',
   'foo2 bar other long string.txt',
   'test foo bar other long string.txt',
   'test test foo qweqwe bar other long string.txt'
];

function f($s) {
   $n = strpos($s, 'foo');
   if ($n === false) {
      return false;
   }
   $n2 = strpos($s, 'bar');
   if ($n2 === false) {
      return false;
   }
   return abs($n2 - $n);
}

function f2($s, $s2) {
   $n = f($s);
   if ($n === false) {
      return 1;
   }
   $n2 = f($s2);
   if ($n2 === false) {
      return -1;
   }
   return $n <=> $n2;
}

usort($a, 'f2');

foreach ($a as $s) {
   echo $s, "\n";
}
```

At first I thought about doing a regular expression, but it's not too easy to do a non-greedy search with something other than a character. So basically I get the index for both substrings, subtract, and take absolute value. I don't think you specified about what should happen with `foo bar` vs `bar foo`, so in this case they are treated equally.

Comment: A brave attempt, but I believe that the "foo bar" is only a test string. It should probably also work for "hot summer night" and "chocolate". Perhaps it is a good idea to report the output in your answer?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware my answer was only meant as a start. OP should go rest of the way themself.

Comment: I agree. The question is quite vague, so you've answered it as well as could be expected.